# How to implement two methods one after the other in Coconut

Tags: python, machine-learning, methods, functional-programming, coconut

Example provided in [coconut documentation](https://coconut.readthedocs.io/en/master/DOCS.html#optimizations)

```py
obj |> .attribute |> .method(args) |> func$(args) |> .[index]
```

However i would like to know how can we apply two methods one after the other that do not return anything, they just modify the object

For example:

##### Coconut

```py
(
    data
    |> Model
    |> .fit()      # does not return anything
    |> .summary()  # therefore, this throws an error
)
```

##### Python

```py
m = Model()
m.fit()
m.summary()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use pipes for this, you can use a [statement lambda](https://coconut.readthedocs.io/en/master/DOCS.html#statement-lambdas) to do

```py
m = (
    data
    |> Model
    |> (def m -> m.fit(); m)
    |> .summary()
)
```

though the Python code will also work in Coconut just fine.